# Confused about GCP Dataproc sofwareConfig values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm attempting to modify Airflow's dataproc operator to include Anaconda and Jupyter to the cluster.

I'm overriding [`DataprocClusterCreateOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/99f22f3f95fd580bfa68d3c582e2bc33b17c6db4/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py#L364) to include `optionalComponents`.

After reading [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/overview) I understand that I need to pass an enum;
Every time I try to run this task I encounter invalid value errors, or `TypeError: Object of type 'EnumMeta' is not JSON serializable`

I'd really appreciate it if someone can tell me how to correctly pass in this field.

```
        cluster_data = {
            'projectId': self.project_id,
            'clusterName': self.cluster_name,
            'config': {
                'gceClusterConfig': {
                },
                'masterConfig': {
                    'numInstances': self.num_masters,
                    'machineTypeUri': master_type_uri,
                    'diskConfig': {
                        'bootDiskType': self.master_disk_type,
                        'bootDiskSizeGb': self.master_disk_size
                    }
                },
                'workerConfig': {
                    'numInstances': self.num_workers,
                    'machineTypeUri': worker_type_uri,
                    'diskConfig': {
                        'bootDiskType': self.worker_disk_type,
                        'bootDiskSizeGb': self.worker_disk_size
                    }
                },
                'secondaryWorkerConfig': {},
                'softwareConfig': {
                         # I've tried the following:
                        'optionalComponents': 'ANACONDA,JUPYTER'
                         #from google.cloud.dataproc_v1 import enums
                         'optionalComponents': [enums.Component.ANACONDA.value]
                },
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a JSON list there `['ANACONDA', 'JUPYTER']`.

As general guidance for figuring out how to structure things, you can create a cluster with `gcloud` and then run:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters describe my-cluster --format json
```

That `--format json` is the key. The result should be directly copy-pastable.